# VueJS bind to a dynamic object by key value

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6

Let's say I ahve this array of objects:

```
data = [

    { id:1, value="a" },
    { id:2, value="b" },
    { id:3, value="c" },
    { id:4, value="d" }

]
```

I need to get the id for each objects and assign the v-model to that object's value by using that id because I'm using [vue-tables-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2) which clones the data so if I used v-model like in a list, the cloned data gets updated and not the original data.

I tried using another way by declaring an associative array:

```
tempData: {}
```

and then saving the value like this:

```
this.tempData[result.id] = result.value
```

but the model doesn't update itself unless a blur event is happened to any of the input forms.

Another way is to use an indexed array:

```
tempData: []
```

which creates undefined indexes that I'm actually scared of because the ids are autoincrementally created. It might have any impact on my data

Comment: Please note that Javascript does not have associative arrays.

Comment: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html I just read it from here

Comment: The author may call it whatever he likes, objects in Javascript are - despite all similarities - not associative arrays. Try `let a = { test: "done" }; Array.isArray(a);`

Comment: @KaySingian It's not very clear what the problem is. Can you give an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @KeySingian how about you clarify more about what you're trying to do and see if the people here can find a workaround for you?